# Overloading operator+ to add class objects stored in a vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to add all of the class objects that are stored in a vector written from a file.

I have overloaded `operator+` in the following way:

```
Force Force::operator+(const Force& f)
{
    forceType = 'c';
    Force result;
    result.xArg = this -> xArg + f.xArg;
    result.yArg =  this -> yArg + f.yArg;
    return(result);
}
```

I want to loop through each line of the file and add all of the `xArg` and `yArg` and display the sum in the end. In all of the tutorials I have seen, the addition is done by creating a separate class object and setting values to it, then creating "Sum" object and just adding the objects together.

My problem is that I don't know how many Forces will be present in the input file, so how would I add the `xArg` and `yArg` to create `Force Sum` object?

Here is some of my class:

```
Force::Force() {};
Force::Force(char fType, float xAr, float yAr)
{
    forceType = fType;
    xArg = xAr;
    yArg = yAr;
}
```

Here is some of my `main` function:

```
void main()
{
    char type;
    float x, y;
    vector <Force> force;
    ifstream file("ForceList.txt");
    assure(file, "ForceList.txt");

    while (file >> type >> x >> y) {
        Force f(type, x, y);
        force.push_back(f);    //stores the class objects in a vector force
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i) {
        force[i].printforce();    //this just prints the vector
    }
```

I'm really new to all of this, so hope this is explained OK and I can get some help.

PS, it is part of a project, and it specifically states that I should use operator overloading to sum up the forces and display the sum.

Comment: It's a good idea to overload operators like `+` and `<` as non-member functions so you can have implicit conversions on both sides.

Comment: Why do you need to know how many there are? You just read them in a loop, and add the one you just read to the total.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why you can't figure this out. Why don't you just do it as if they are ints? Have a running total, and add all of the objects to it in a loop.

Comment: Create a Force object called sum. And now loop the file and keep adding it to sum. That's it.

Comment: @Barmar how would i do that with the class objects though? that's exactly my problem - i can't seem to grasp how to do that

Comment: I think my brain got fried, i have been thinking over this for so long, that's why i can't figure out something that seems so simple (even to myself)

Comment: The same way as with `int`: `total = total + force_you_just_read;`

Comment: You may want to add member function `operator+=`, also `operator+` can be expressed by `+=` easily.

Comment: BTW, your `operator+` changes the `forcetype` of one of the input forces, not the new force that it's returning.

Comment: @Ana please remember to [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), when appropriate.  Leaving "thank you" comments leaves all your questions unresolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all your `operator+` is implemented incorrectly, for expression:

```
x = a + b;
```

`this` for your `operator+` would point to `&a`, so assignment to `forceType` in it is logically wrong. So you either should make that method `const` (and compiler would reject such assignment) or maybe even better to make it non member (possibly friend) or static and this error would become obvious:

```
 Force operator+( const Force &a, const Force &b ) // non member or static
 {
     forceType = 'c'; // error where forceType belongs to?
     ...
 }
```

Another thing it could be easier to implement `operator+=` instead:

```
Force &Force::operator+=(const Force& f) 
{
    forceType = 'c';
    xArg += f.xArg;
    yArg += f.yArg;
    return *this;
}
```

then `operator+` is trivial:

```
Force operator+( const Force &a, const Force &b )
{
    Force r( a );
    r += b;
    return r;
}
```

but your loop could use `+=` directly:

```
sum += newobject;
```

PS to avoid confusion and understand why `forceType = 'c';` is incorrect in your code and fine in mine look at this:

```
a + b; // the same as
a.operator+( b ); // it is not correct to change forceType for a
```

on my case:

```
a += b; // the same as
a.operator+=( b ); // a is expected to be changed including forceType member
```

Comment: can i have a little bit more information on your implementation of `operator+=` please?

Answer (score 1):

```
Force sum('c',0,0);

while (file >> type >> x >> y) {
    Force f(type, x, y);
    sum = sum + f; // operator overloading is active here 
}
```

> Make sure you write another overload for '**=**'

Comment: I think the default assignment operator will work here.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways of accomplishing your goal:

1. Overload `operator+=`. Then use it in a loop to update an object.
2. Overload `operator+`. Then use it in a loop to update an object.

If you use `operator+=`, you will need something like:

```
Force sum; // Assuming the default constructor is good enough
for ( auto& item : force ) {
   sum += item;
}
```

If you use `operator+`, you will need something like:

```
Force sum;
for ( auto& item : force ) {
   sum = sum + item;
}
```

It's worth noting that:

1. Using `operator+=` is more efficient since it involves less copying.
2. `operator+` can be implemented in terms of `operator+=`.

---

```
Force& operator+=(Force const& rhs)
{
   this->type = 'c'; // ???
   this->xArg += rhs.xArg;
   this->yArg += rhs.yArg;
   return *this;
}

Force operator+(Force const& rhs) const
{
   Force ret = *this;
   return (ret += rhs);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    char type;
    float x, y;
    vector<Force> force;

    ifstream file("ForceList.txt");
    assure(file, "ForceList.txt");

    while (file >> type >> x >> y) {
        Force f(type, x, y);
        force.push_back(f);
    }

    Force sum('c', 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < force.size(); ++i) {
        sum = sum + force[i];
    }

    sum.printforce();
    return 0;
}
```